# script execute every day to send orders to a device

Tags: php

Hello i need to know if this script is correct.

The goal is to send to a device a checkout if the day of checkout is equal to today.

Is my if condition is good to compare two date ?

```
$today = new DateTime(); // ex :20-09-2021

foreach($orders as $order){
    $checkout = new Checkout();
    $checkout->get($order['id']);
    $delivery_date = new DateTime($checkout->day);
    $restaurant = $checkout->getRestaurant();
    //is the some date
    if($delivery_date->diff($today)->days === 0 ) {
        if (isset($restaurant->token) && !empty($restaurant->token)) {
            if ($popina_response = Foxorders_Popina::sendNewOrder($checkout)) {
                $checkout->popina_notified = 1;
                $checkout->popina_response = $popina_response;
            }
            if (($popina_response == '{"ok":true}') || ($popina_response == 'Shop not found') || ($popina_response == '{"error":"Shop not found"}')) {
                $checkout->popina_retry = 0;
            }
            $checkout->save();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `$today` contain? It is not defined in the question. Did you declare it?

Comment: thanks for your reply,$today contain date of today

Comment: OK, that's good, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to compare two dates.

Comment: but if i run this code in php  console ```<?php
        //Enter your code here, enjoy!

$today = new DateTime();
$delivery_date = new DateTime("21-09-2021");

if($delivery_date->diff($today)->days === 0 ) {
    
    echo 'yes';
} else {
    echo 'no';

}``` it return no

Comment: It doesn't matter if you run it from the command line interface, a web browser, or as a cron job, in all cases you will be comparing two dates correctly this way.

Comment: Let me test that.

Comment: When I run the code you gave it returned "yes". See: [Code demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0ed6b13ed3f88134e487d4d272a8c69b74c99fee).

Comment: yes but today is 20-09-2021

Comment: Ah, good point. Yes, that is weird. Let me check.

Comment: Ah, I see that my assumption that you did this correctly is wrong. `DateTime::diff()` gives the total difference between two dates. So only when two dates are further apart than 24 hours they will be a day apart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DateTime::diff()` gives the total difference between two dates. So only when two dates are further apart than 24 hours they will be a day apart.

A better way to compare dates is:

```
if (($delivery_date->format('Y-m-d') == $today->format('Y-m-d')) {
    .....
}
```

This converts two `DateTime` objects to strings, containing the dates, which are then compared.

Instead of `$today->format('Y-m-d')` you could write: `date('Y-m-d')`.

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports PHP 8, you can do this:

```
$today = date('d-m-Y');
$delivery_date = '20-09-2021';

if (str_contains($today, $delivery_date)) { };
```

[Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e3d055edd066e23d700c81d5e677ed6be3afb4c)